# Is it legal to make a copy of initilizer_list in lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, initializer-list

Please consider this simplified C++14 program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto l12 = {1,2};
    auto copy = []( auto v ) { return v; };
    std::vector<int> v{ copy( l12 ) };
    std::cout << v[0] << ' ' << v[1] << '\n';
}
```

GCC here issues the warning:

```
warning: returning local 'initializer_list' variable 'v' does not extend the lifetime of the underlying array [-Winit-list-lifetime]
    7 |     auto copy = []( auto v ) { return v; };
```

while other compilers accept the program: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PPrsWxbfM

Could you please say whether the program is ill-formed or GCC warning is wrong?

Comment: I think it is kind of an illusion that `std::initializer_list` are copyable. The compiler might be warning about that, even though in the larger context is ok.

Comment: Having said that, a "proper" copy function is actually a bit different: `auto copy = [](auto const& v){return v;};`. For this one, the compiler doesn't complain, for whatever reason. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r1jY98rqr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well-formed, and there is no UB.

`auto l12` extends the lifetime of the temporary array, and keeps it alive until the end of `main`. `auto v` and the return value of the lambda don't extend anything, but it's not a problem as long as `l12` is alive.

---

But in general, I wouldn't recommend using `std::initializer_list` for anything other than a function parameter, because of the tricky lifetime extension rules.